# My Fragment hides the Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation Drawer in my App. If i select a particular item and slide the navigation drawer. The Fragment overlaps the navigation Drawer.

I Tried to add `popBackStackImmediate();` But it is of no use. This is how it looks like

[image]

**Activity**

```
public class Activity extends MainActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (position == 1)
        {
            HomeFragment Frag = new HomeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, Frag);
            transaction.commit();
        }
        else if (position == 2)
        {

        }
    }
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerview)
    {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    }
```

**Navigation Fragment**

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks
{
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";
    private static final String PREFERENCES_FILE = "my_app_settings"; 
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private RecyclerView mDrawerList;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mDrawerList.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final List<NavigationItem> navigationItems = getMenu();
        NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(navigationItems);
        adapter.setNavigationDrawerCallbacks(this);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readSharedSetting(getActivity(), PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false"));
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try
        {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    public ActionBarDrawerToggle getActionBarDrawerToggle()
    {
        return mActionBarDrawerToggle;
    }

    public void setActionBarDrawerToggle(ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle)
    {
        mActionBarDrawerToggle = actionBarDrawerToggle;
    }

    public void setup(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar)
    {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
        {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView)
            {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);               
                if (!isAdded())
                    return;
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
            {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded())
                    return;
                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer)
                {
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    saveSharedSetting(getActivity(), PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "true");
                }               
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState)
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);

        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);
    }

    public void openDrawer()
    {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    public void closeDrawer()
    {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach()
    {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    public List<NavigationItem> getMenu()
    {
        List<NavigationItem> items = new ArrayList<NavigationItem>();
        items.add(new NavigationItem("Home", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play)));
        items.add(new NavigationItem("News", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play)));
        items.add(new NavigationItem("Videos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play)));
        items.add(new NavigationItem("Playlist", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play)));
        return items;
    }

    void selectItem(int position)
    {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerLayout != null)
        {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null)
        {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
        ((NavigationDrawerAdapter) mDrawerList.getAdapter()).selectPosition(position);
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen()
    {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position)
    {
        mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        selectItem(position);

    }

    public DrawerLayout getDrawerLayout()
    {
        return mDrawerLayout;
    }

    public void setDrawerLayout(DrawerLayout drawerLayout)
    {
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    }
}
```

**Activity Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <!-- android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"-->
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
            android:name="com.RemoteIt.client.activity.drawer.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**HomeFragment**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment
{

    public HomeFragment()
    {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);

        int redActionButtonSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.red_action_button_size);
        int redActionButtonMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.action_button_margin);
        int redActionButtonContentSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.red_action_button_content_size);
        int redActionButtonContentMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.red_action_button_content_margin);
        int redActionMenuRadius = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.red_action_menu_radius);
        int blueSubActionButtonSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.blue_sub_action_button_size);
        int blueSubActionButtonContentMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.blue_sub_action_button_content_margin);

        ImageView fabIconStar = new ImageView(getActivity());
        fabIconStar.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_important));

        FloatingActionButton.LayoutParams starParams = new FloatingActionButton.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        starParams.setMargins(redActionButtonMargin, redActionButtonMargin, redActionButtonMargin, redActionButtonMargin);
        fabIconStar.setLayoutParams(starParams);

        FloatingActionButton.LayoutParams fabIconStarParams = new FloatingActionButton.LayoutParams(redActionButtonContentSize, redActionButtonContentSize);
        fabIconStarParams.setMargins(redActionButtonContentMargin, redActionButtonContentMargin, redActionButtonContentMargin, redActionButtonContentMargin);

        FloatingActionButton leftCenterButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(getActivity()).setContentView(fabIconStar, fabIconStarParams).setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.button_action_red_selector).setPosition(FloatingActionButton.POSITION_TOP_CENTER).setLayoutParams(starParams).build();

        // Set up customized SubActionButtons for the right center menu
        SubActionButton.Builder lCSubBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(getActivity());
        lCSubBuilder.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_action_blue_selector));

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams blueContentParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        blueContentParams.setMargins(blueSubActionButtonContentMargin, blueSubActionButtonContentMargin, blueSubActionButtonContentMargin, blueSubActionButtonContentMargin);
        lCSubBuilder.setLayoutParams(blueContentParams);
        // Set custom layout params
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams blueParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(blueSubActionButtonSize, blueSubActionButtonSize);
        lCSubBuilder.setLayoutParams(blueParams);

        ImageView lcIcon1 = new ImageView(getActivity());
        ImageView lcIcon2 = new ImageView(getActivity());
        ImageView lcIcon3 = new ImageView(getActivity());
        ImageView lcIcon4 = new ImageView(getActivity());
        ImageView lcIcon5 = new ImageView(getActivity());
        ImageView lcIcon6 = new ImageView(getActivity());
        ImageView lcIcon7 = new ImageView(getActivity());
        ImageView lcIcon8 = new ImageView(getActivity());
        ImageView lcIcon9 = new ImageView(getActivity());

        lcIcon1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_camera));
        lcIcon2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_picture));
        lcIcon3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_video));
        lcIcon4.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_location_found));
        lcIcon5.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_headphones));
        lcIcon6.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_camera));
        lcIcon7.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_picture));
        lcIcon8.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_video));
        lcIcon9.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_location_found));

        // Build another menu with custom options
        FloatingActionMenu leftCenterMenu = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder(getActivity()).addSubActionView(lCSubBuilder.setContentView(lcIcon1, blueContentParams).build()).addSubActionView(lCSubBuilder.setContentView(lcIcon2, blueContentParams).build()).addSubActionView(lCSubBuilder.setContentView(lcIcon3, blueContentParams).build()).addSubActionView(lCSubBuilder.setContentView(lcIcon4, blueContentParams).build()).addSubActionView(lCSubBuilder.setContentView(lcIcon5, blueContentParams).build())
                .addSubActionView(lCSubBuilder.setContentView(lcIcon6, blueContentParams).build()).addSubActionView(lCSubBuilder.setContentView(lcIcon7, blueContentParams).build()).addSubActionView(lCSubBuilder.setContentView(lcIcon8, blueContentParams).build()).addSubActionView(lCSubBuilder.setContentView(lcIcon9, blueContentParams).build()).setRadius(redActionMenuRadius).setStartAngle(0).setEndAngle(360).attachTo(leftCenterButton).build();

        return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post your layout xml as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following changes were made to the `FloatingActionButton` and `FloatingActionMenu` classes to allow a specific ViewGroup to be set as the container for both. Tests were made with a similar but simpler version of the code you've posted, so you may need to make adjustments to your setup parameters.

The library code assumes that the Button and Menu are to appear on top of an Activity's content View, and everything therein. The addition of a container ViewGroup member in the `FloatingActionButton` class allows us to specify a child ViewGroup to be the parent instead. Please note that the following changes will only work if a `FloatingActionButton` is used with the Menu.

The additions to the `FloatingActionButton` class:

```
public class FloatingActionButton extends FrameLayout {
    ...
    private ViewGroup containerView;
    ...
    public FloatingActionButton(Activity activity, 
                                LayoutParams layoutParams, 
                                int theme,
                                Drawable backgroundDrawable,
                                int position,
                                View contentView,
                                FrameLayout.LayoutParams contentParams      
                                // Note the addition of the following
                                // constructor parameter here
                                , ViewGroup containerView) {
        ...
        setClickable(true);

        // This line is new. The rest of the constructor is the same.
        this.containerView = containerView;     

        attach(layoutParams);
    }
    ...
    public View getActivityContentView() {
        if(containerView == null) {
            return ((Activity)getContext())
                .getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        } else {
            return containerView;
        }
    }

    public ViewGroup getContainerView() {
        return containerView;
    }

    // The following setter is not strictly necessary, but may be of use
    // if you want to toggle the Button's and Menu's z-order placement
    public void setContainerView(ViewGroup containerView) {
        this.containerView = containerView;
    }
    ...
    public static class Builder {
        ...
        private ViewGroup containerView;
        ...
        public Builder setContainerView(ViewGroup containerView) {
            this.containerView = containerView;
            return this;
        }

        public FloatingActionButton build() {
            return new FloatingActionButton(activity,
                                            layoutParams,
                                            theme,
                                            backgroundDrawable,
                                            position,
                                            contentView,
                                            contentParams,
                                            // New argument
                                            containerView);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And the changes to the `FloatingActionMenu` class:

```
public class FloatingActionMenu {
    ...
    public View getActivityContentView() {
        if(mainActionView instanceof FloatingActionButton && 
            ((FloatingActionButton) mainActionView).getContainerView() != null) {
            return ((FloatingActionButton) mainActionView).getContainerView();
        } else {
            return ((Activity)mainActionView.getContext())
                .getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Then, in the Fragment's `onCreateView()` method, we need to add a call the new `setContainerView()` method of the `FloatingActionButton.Builder` class.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ...
        FloatingActionButton leftCenterButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(getActivity())
            .setContentView(fabIconStar, null)
            .setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setPosition(FloatingActionButton.POSITION_TOP_CENTER)
            .setLayoutParams(starParams)
            // The new method call is added here
            .setContainerView(container)
            .build();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that you can still use the modified library as originally intended - i.e., z-ordered above the whole Activity - by simply omitting the `setContainerView()` call on the `Builder`.

Comment: It works for the drawer. But when i go from Fragment A to Fragment B. The FloatingActionbutton is not being replaced ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What doesn't change? The images? Just the Button, or the whole Menu? Does each Fragment have a different Button and Menu? Does just the HomeFragment have a Button/Menu that should be gone when you switch to another Fragment? Are you sure the second Fragment is loading correctly?

Comment: See here http://i.imgur.com/GCH3PZX.png In Fragment B, I have only a listview and a blue button. The Red Floating button is from the Fragment A. I don't know why it is not Replacing

Comment: I've figured out the reason for that, but, first, are you sure this library is appropriate to your use case? You're not exactly using it as it was meant to be used. Might it be better (I'm just guessing this from the code and images given) to scavenge it for the View placements and animations, rather than trying to cram it awkwardly into your already-conceived design?

Comment: Yeah I understand it. But my App needs something like this ?

Comment: I added this line `containerView.removeView(this)` to the `FloatingActionbutton` and made `leftCenterButton` and `leftCenterMenu` as `class members`. Did i do Right ? or you want to remove the views from the `HomeFragment` ?

Comment: If i Change the `setContatinerView()`. The Button changes it's postition and it Force Closes.

Comment: I'm Confused. I don't know how to Remove that leftCenterButton from the Fragment. There is No Easy way to do it ?

Comment: I changed my implementation to Activity. But still the menu overlays the navigation Drawer.

Comment: @Arul Please ignore my previous comment; my apologies. I was having an off day. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike. I solved it by using activity instead of fragment. Will meet u in the Future Questions :P

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the below line of code

```
transaction.replace(R.id.container, Frag);
```

with

```
transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, Frag);
```

I had this overlapping issue once due to **android.R.id.content** and i replaced it with **R.id.content_frame** which solved my issue.

But i see in your code that you have used a different container view ID, but this should work though.

Comment: There is no id called R.id.content ?

Comment: It is "android.R.id.content" and not "R.id.content". Also you should be using "R.id.content_frame" as mentioned above.