# How to Bring my Navigation Drawer to Front?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-viewgroup

I am using this circular menu for my App.
https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu
It is working. But when i open my Navigation Drawer. This Menu is in the front. How can i make the Menu to go Back to the Navigation Drawer.

How Can i Bring my Navigation Drawer to Front ?

[image]

```
public class Home extends MainActivity implements OnClickListener
{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        this.application = (Remtt) this.getApplication();
        this.preferences = this.application.getPreferences();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.checkOnCreate();

            int redActionButtonSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.red_action_button_size);
            int redActionButtonMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.action_button_margin);
            int redActionButtonContentSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.red_action_button_content_size);
            int redActionButtonContentMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.red_action_button_content_margin);
            int redActionMenuRadius = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.red_action_menu_radius);
            int blueSubActionButtonSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.blue_sub_action_button_size);
            int blueSubActionButtonContentMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.blue_sub_action_button_content_margin);

            ImageView fabIconStar = new ImageView(this);
            fabIconStar.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_headphones));

            FloatingActionButton.LayoutParams starParams = new FloatingActionButton.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            starParams.setMargins(redActionButtonMargin, redActionButtonMargin, redActionButtonMargin, redActionButtonMargin);
            fabIconStar.setLayoutParams(starParams);

            FloatingActionButton.LayoutParams fabIconStarParams = new FloatingActionButton.LayoutParams(redActionButtonContentSize, redActionButtonContentSize);
            fabIconStarParams.setMargins(redActionButtonContentMargin, redActionButtonContentMargin, redActionButtonContentMargin, redActionButtonContentMargin);

            FloatingActionButton leftCenterButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this).setContentView(fabIconStar, fabIconStarParams).setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.button_action_red_selector).setPosition(FloatingActionButton.POSITION_TOP_CENTER).setLayoutParams(starParams).build();

            // Set up customized SubActionButtons for the right center menu
            SubActionButton.Builder lCSubBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(this);
            lCSubBuilder.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_action_blue_selector));

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams blueContentParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            blueContentParams.setMargins(blueSubActionButtonContentMargin, blueSubActionButtonContentMargin, blueSubActionButtonContentMargin, blueSubActionButtonContentMargin);
            lCSubBuilder.setLayoutParams(blueContentParams);
            // Set custom layout params
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams blueParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(blueSubActionButtonSize, blueSubActionButtonSize);
            lCSubBuilder.setLayoutParams(blueParams);

            ImageView lcIcon1 = new ImageView(this);
            ImageView lcIcon2 = new ImageView(this);
            ImageView lcIcon3 = new ImageView(this);
            ImageView lcIcon4 = new ImageView(this);
            ImageView lcIcon5 = new ImageView(this);
            ImageView lcIcon6 = new ImageView(this);
            ImageView lcIcon7 = new ImageView(this);
            ImageView lcIcon8 = new ImageView(this);
            ImageView lcIcon9 = new ImageView(this);

            lcIcon1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.anim));
            lcIcon2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.anim));
            lcIcon3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.anim));
            lcIcon4.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.anim));
            lcIcon5.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_headphones));
            lcIcon6.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.anim));
            lcIcon7.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.anim));
            lcIcon8.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.anim));
            lcIcon9.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.anim));

            // Build another menu with custom options
            FloatingActionMenu leftCenterMenu = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder(this).addSubActionView(lCSubBuilder.setContentView(lcIcon1, blueContentParams).build()).addSubActionView(lCSubBuilder.setContentView(lcIcon2, blueContentParams).build()).addSubActionView(lCSubBuilder.setContentView(lcIcon3, blueContentParams).build()).addSubActionView(lCSubBuilder.setContentView(lcIcon4, blueContentParams).build()).addSubActionView(lCSubBuilder.setContentView(lcIcon5, blueContentParams).build())
                    .addSubActionView(lCSubBuilder.setContentView(lcIcon6, blueContentParams).build()).addSubActionView(lCSubBuilder.setContentView(lcIcon7, blueContentParams).build()).addSubActionView(lCSubBuilder.setContentView(lcIcon8, blueContentParams).build()).addSubActionView(lCSubBuilder.setContentView(lcIcon9, blueContentParams).build()).setRadius(redActionMenuRadius).setStartAngle(0).setEndAngle(360).attachTo(leftCenterButton).build();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use method bringtofront() or use framelayout.

Comment: Modify the library. Change the method FloatingActionMenu.getActivityContentView() and return the viewgroup that holds your activity content - the one defined inside DrawerLayout tags in xml.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067440/my-fragment-hides-the-navigation-drawer

Comment: @MikeM. It was very useful. How can i pass the Viewgroup from my Activity to this method setContainerView()?

Comment: It should be the content ViewGroup in your DrawerLayout. That is, the first thing listed within the DrawerLayout; usually a FrameLayout. For example: `FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);`. If you need more specifics, you'll have to post your Activity's layout xml.

Comment: Post the layout of the `Activity`.

Comment: I think you are adding the floating navigation bar to the activity rather than the framelayout of the fragment .Can you post the XML file of the activity

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067440/my-fragment-hides-the-navigation-drawer), with only minor changes to the `FloatingActionButton` instantiation.

The library code assumes that the Button and Menu are to appear on top of an Activity's content View, and everything therein. The addition of a container ViewGroup member in the `FloatingActionButton` class allows us to specify a child ViewGroup to be the parent instead. Please note that the following changes will only work if a `FloatingActionButton` is used with the Menu.

The additions to the `FloatingActionButton` class:

```
public class FloatingActionButton extends FrameLayout {
    ...
    private ViewGroup containerView;
    ...
    public FloatingActionButton(Activity activity, 
                                LayoutParams layoutParams, 
                                int theme,
                                Drawable backgroundDrawable,
                                int position,
                                View contentView,
                                FrameLayout.LayoutParams contentParams      
                                // Note the addition of the following
                                // constructor parameter here
                                , ViewGroup containerView) {
        ...
        setClickable(true);

        // This line is new. The rest of the constructor is the same.
        this.containerView = containerView;     

        attach(layoutParams);
    }
    ...
    public View getActivityContentView() {
        if(containerView == null) {
            return ((Activity)getContext())
                .getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        } else {
            return containerView;
        }
    }

    public ViewGroup getContainerView() {
        return containerView;
    }

    // The following setter is not strictly necessary, but may be of use
    // if you want to toggle the Button's and Menu's z-order placement
    public void setContainerView(ViewGroup containerView) {
        this.containerView = containerView;
    }
    ...
    public static class Builder {
        ...
        private ViewGroup containerView;
        ...
        public Builder setContainerView(ViewGroup containerView) {
            this.containerView = containerView;
            return this;
        }

        public FloatingActionButton build() {
            return new FloatingActionButton(activity,
                                            layoutParams,
                                            theme,
                                            backgroundDrawable,
                                            position,
                                            contentView,
                                            contentParams,
                                            // New argument
                                            containerView);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And the changes to the `FloatingActionMenu` class:

```
public class FloatingActionMenu {
    ...
    public View getActivityContentView() {
        if(mainActionView instanceof FloatingActionButton && 
            ((FloatingActionButton) mainActionView).getContainerView() != null) {
            return ((FloatingActionButton) mainActionView).getContainerView();
        } else {
            return ((Activity)mainActionView.getContext())
                .getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Then, assuming your Activity's layout is similar to:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ...>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    ...
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In your `Home` Activity, you would build and instantiate `leftCenterButton` like so:

```
public class Home extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

        FloatingActionButton leftCenterButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
            .setContentView(fabIconStar, null)
            .setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setPosition(FloatingActionButton.POSITION_TOP_CENTER)
            .setLayoutParams(starParams)
            // The new method call is added here
            .setContainerView(container)
            .build();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```